# How to make a loop to create several contingency tables using columns from my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

How to make a loop to create several contingency tables using columns from my dataframe?

This is part of my data frame:

```
structure(list(`Nombre del encuestado` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Dim = 20L, class = "table"), Municipio = c("IPIALES", 
"IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", 
"IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", 
"IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", "IPIALES", 
"ARBOLEDA"), `Cuenta con sistema de Riego:` = c("NO", "NO", "NO", 
"SI", "SI", "NO", "NO", "NO", "SI", "NO", "SI", "NO", "NO", "SI", 
"SI", "NO", "NO", "SI", "NO", "NO"), `Procedencia del agua:` = c("Lluvia", 
"Lluvia", "Lluvia", "Acueducto", "Acueducto", "Lluvia", "Lluvia", 
"Lluvia", "Acueducto", "Lluvia", "Acueducto", "Lluvia", "Lluvia", 
"Acueducto", "Acueducto", "Lluvia", "Lluvia", "Acueducto", "Lluvia", 
"Lluvia"), `Cuenta con certificación en:` = c("Ningúna", "Ningúna", 
"Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", 
"Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", 
"Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "Ningúna", "BPA", "Ningúna")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to use table function for each column with df$Municipio variable, somethink like this:

```
table(df$Municipio,
      df$`Cuenta con sistema de Riego:`)
```

Results:

```
              NO SI
  ARBOLEDA    19  5
  El Peñol    11  9
  IPIALES     12  7
  La Florida  14  6
  Providencia 19  1
  Sandona     17  2
```

Again:

```
table(df$Municipio,
      df$`Procedencia del agua:`)
```

Results:

```
            Acueducto Lluvia Rio/Qubrada/Nacimiento
  ARBOLEDA            0     19                      5
  El Peñol            6     11                      3
  IPIALES             7     12                      0
  La Florida          0     14                      6
  Providencia         0     19                      1
  Sandona             2     17                      0
```

Please, help me!

Many thanks

make a loop to create several contingency tables using columns from my dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Municipio` is the second column, loop over all the columns with either `index`ing (`-2`) and get the `table` of other column with the second column and store the output in a `list`

```
lapply(df[-2], function(x) table(x, df[[2]]))
```

Or use column names

```
lapply(setdiff(names(df), "Municipio"), function(nm) table(df[[nm]],
           df$Municipio))
```